# Mobile Safari - Bottom Navigation Issue - CSS and Polymer

Tags: ios, css, polymer

I am currently working on a project using Google's Polymer project.  The issue that I am having occurs only in Safari on iOS.  In the current chat view that I am working on, when a user scrolls through the chats everything works great. It is when the user taps on the keyboard there is then this gap that sticks and is difficult to get rid of.

Please see the images below and if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

I have several more pictures but I am unable to post due to my reputation being less than 10. Thank you to everyone in advance for any help.

[Here is what happens after the keyboard has been opened and put away. You can see in the image that there is now a gap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czOCt.png)

Here is the CSS for the container

```
.message-sender-container {
    @apply --layout-horizontal;
    @apply --layout-center;
    @apply --layout-around-justified;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    bottom: 2%;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="message-sender-container">
  <paper-textarea id="message" label="Message..."></paper-textarea>
  <paper-button id="image-btn" on-tap="_onTapImageBtn" class="flex" dialog-confirm autofocus raised type="submit"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:insert-photo"></iron-icon></paper-button>
  <paper-button id="send-btn" on-tap="_onTapSendDialogBtn" dialog-confirm autofocus raised type="submit"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:send"></iron-icon></paper-button>
</div>
```

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please ad some code so we can help you

Comment: I have added both CSS and html to this post.

Comment: I figured this out on my own. This is an issue with Safari's mobile browser so I decided to change the layout so that in Safari it did not have this issue.

Comment: next time add a @andrewstanley tag so I get the notification. If you have any more questions I'm happy to help